# Trying to call an external php file on form submit, Getting 404 error

Tags: php, forms

I have a form which is being echoed by php:

```
echo '<form action="stsupport.php" method="POST">
<p>
Priority Name: <input type="text" size="50" name="ticketpriority" placeholder="Input a name for your priority..."></textarea>
</p>

<input type="submit" name="submitpriority" value="submit">

</form>';
```

I want the stsupport php file to run when the form is submitted but I am getting 404 error when the form is submitted.

The stsupport.php file is in the same folder as the file with the form.

Any ideas?

Edit:

This is in the support.php file where i call the function to create priority.
The create priority function just displays the form above.

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content\plugins\stsupport\adminmenu.php');

create_priority();
```

When the form is submitted i want to run:

```
function st_support(){
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content\plugins\stsupport\adminmenu.php');

    create_priority();

    if (isset($data['submitpriority'])) {
        insert_priority();
    }
}
```

The insert_priority function is inside the adminmenu.php file

Comment: u r opening input type and closing textarea why?

Comment: @Vicky - thanks, didn't see that, it made no difference though.

Comment: yeah i no!! this will make no difference !!

Comment: did you try putting in the full path? i.e. `form action="http://www.example.com/stsupport.php"` (or whatever your site is)

Comment: i think there might be some file permission problem if the file in same location as u said!!

Comment: Are you using URL RE-Writing ?

Comment: @ManishShukla - no im not using url rewriting. All of the redirecting is done on a single page with forms

Comment: if you can add redirecting code then i can help you better

Comment: Are you able to load this PHP file in your web browser (without submitting a form to it), and it loads without a 404?

Comment: @ManishShukla - edits are in the question.

Comment: @Shane - yes, the support.php file is the file that calls the function to display the form, so it is working fine

Comment: @mgrantnz - I mean the destination PHP file, the one referred to in your action. If you manually load that one, do you still get a 404? If it were file permissions, you're more likely to get a 403.

Answer (score 0):

Try open stsupport.php via browser

Check your htaccess rule, if exist

Check file permission

Or

```
if(file_exists('stsupport.php')){
    $action = 'stsupport.php';
}else{
    $action = '';
}
echo '<form action="'. $action .'" method="POST">
<p>
Priority Name: <input type="text" size="50" name="ticketpriority" placeholder="Input a name for your priority..."></textarea>
</p>

<input type="submit" name="submitpriority" value="submit">

</form>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to type the the full directory of the root folder in the form. also set the name of the form as the name attribute in the input tag.
`'<form name='submitpriority' action="../DIRECTORY/stsupport.php" method="POST">`